# How do I create a discord.js command in index.js [The bot's startup file] that deletes the message when a message that contains "hi" was sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've tried to create a command where the bot waits for a message that was sent until a message contained "thebotdeletesthismessage", the bot doesn't seem to do anything, the language I've used is node.js.

The bot doesn't really responds neither delete the message, I've tried to change the code a little bit, Still nothing, I need to know what I've done wrong here.

If you didn't understand something, Please let me know in the comments, And please don't close this topic, I really need help.

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.starts("thebotdeletesthismessage")) {
    message.delete
    message.channel.send('No, dont send that.');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `message.delete` to `message.delete()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `.starts()` method, you probably want to use [`.startsWith()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete). Also, [`message.delete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete) is not a property but a method, so you'll need to use parentheses after that.

The following code will delete every message that starts with `"thebotdeletesthismessage"` and sends a message instead:

```js
bot.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('thebotdeletesthismessage')) {
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send("No, don't send that.");
  }
});
```

[image]